# Proper routing configuration for multiple apis sharing same endpoint

Tags: c#, xml, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I have a working API with a different endpoint -- a different controller -- for each type of XML post data that I expect to receive.  Now, the client wants us to use the same endpoint for everything. The only determination of direction is the content of the XML data -- basically by the name of the root element.

I'd like to be able to leverage as much of my existing work as possible, so I am trying to add a new controller "Router" which does exactly that -- redirects to the proper route based on the content received. I've tried some things but can't seem to get any traction.

If there is a better way to handle this, I would be open to hearing about it.

```
        // WebApiConfig.cs
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            //routeTemplate: "Router",
            constraints: null,
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

//In RouteConfig.cs -- is this redundant to specific MapRoute and MapHttpRoute?

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(name: "First", url: "First/{action}/{id}" );
        routes.MapRoute(name: "Second", url: "Second/{action}/{id}" );
        routes.MapRoute(name: "Third", url: "Third/{action}/{id}" );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", 
                            action = "Index", 
                            id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

But at any rate, I do have my APi traffic hitting the RouterController 
(and I will admit I'm not completely clear why it's working) but once
there, how do I go about rerouting based on the XML data posted?

```
public RouterController()
{
    log.Debug("Inside RouterController");
}


public IHttpActionResult Post(object postdata)
{
    // how to determine the postdata contents / XML structure to get the 
    // root element and then redirect to the "true" controller?
}
```

Several questions here:  First, why the (apparent) redundancy in WebApiConfig.cs route definition and RouteConfig.cs routing?  Second, what's the best way to recognize traffic by its content and route appropriately?

Thanks for your assistance.  I'll admit to running fairly blind here, so any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not a good idea to have some xml parsing logic in your routes (if it's even possible).

Based on you description I guess that you have many controller methods and models for them. You can keep them almost unchanged, maybe only making methods private.

```
public class First
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Second
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private void HandleFirst(First model)
{
    // Your existing code
}

private void HandleSecond(Second second)
{
    // Your existing code
}
```

My suggestion is to have one controller method (how your client wants) that will do the following things:

1. Accept raw request data
2. Parse XML and get know the type
3. Create model by deserializing XML
4. Call needed method

That is how it might look:

```
public void Post(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result))
    {
        xmlReader.MoveToContent();
        switch (xmlReader.Name)
        {
            case "First":
                HandleFirst(Deserialize<First>(xmlReader));
                break;
            case "Second":
                HandleSecond(Deserialize<Second>(xmlReader));
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}

private T Deserialize<T>(XmlReader xmlReader)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    return (T)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
}
```

In this case you can keep you routing configuration very simple. All you need is to use default one. You might also take a closer look at [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) that was introduced in Web.API 2.

Comment: Thanks so much, this was very helpful.  I am about half-way done with re-tooling in this manner and so far things are working peachy.  Appreciate it!

Comment: So, some of my classes are nested xml structures.  When I execute Deserialize<NestedClass>(xmlReader), any element that is a direct child of the root element is created properly in the new NestedClass object, but any elements below that, and their children, are all null. I've been tangling with this for hours and can't figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: I think you need to ask new question. Add your XML samples and classes that you are using for serialization. You can add a question link as a comment here.

Comment: FINALLY discovered the issue, it was a problem in the XML that I was posting that was masking the true nature of the problem.  Thanks again, I'm up and running!